# React native + WebView: scrollEnabled={false} for android?

Tags: react-native, webview

In ReactNative WebView, is there any way to achieves the same effect as scrollEnabled={false} in android (works only for ios)?

I need to wrap the webView with ScrollView (as I want to control the scrolling and its mush more complicated to do that in the WebView's html-content) and android devices crashed in this case.